# How to get the username of a person in php facebook sdk

Tags: php, facebook

I don't know I'm sounding stupid or not? 

I am trying to find the username of a person in facebook through php. Is that at all possible??

Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: Since Graph API v2.0, it's no longer possible to get the username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Username is not available in API v2.0 and later. So no it is not possible get the username from a user id or the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

what data you have?
if you have uid you can find by:
http://graph.facebook.com/yourUID

example 
http://graph.facebook.com/1503382632

if you want put to php you can get

```
 <?php 

$request_url ="http://graph.facebook.com/1503382632";

$requests = file_get_contents($request_url);

$fb_user = json_decode($requests);

echo $fb_user->username; //this will outpun username

?>
```

Comment: But I need that username to find the uid. So Is there Any Other Way Without Using The uid

Comment: who person you want find?

Comment: That depends on the user input

Comment: what is the user input? Name?

Comment: the one way only  i know is: 
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/friends'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();   

then save all friend uid,username, and name in database then find name by select from database

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have enough rep to post it as comment.
 @A'aqu the `$request_url` must be `https` instead of `http` and it should be more like `https://graph.facebook.com/yourUID?access_token=yourAccessToken` rather than just `http://graph.facebook.com/yourUID`.
Please update your answer

Comment: Hmm, as far as I can tell, you DO have enough rep to turn this into a comment on the answer you are referring to...

Comment: @Yunnosch I've enough rep now..not at the time when I posted it as an answer, plus now I don't even see the answer of that A'aqu guy on which I was gonna comment